Overlap parts of a single mesh on the same UV map
My tree consists of two objects: leaves and tree (trunk). All leaf meshes are identical (every of them consists of two flat trapezoids):

I would like to use the same leaf texture for all leaves, so I need to unwrap all leaves precisely overlaping them on top of each other on UV space. At first (by default) it was so, but then I did unwraping manually, and I don't know how to get something like that for all leaves:

ADDED: It looks like all leaves have the same UV map, but visually some leaves have stretched textures.




You unwrap one leaf, then just use the same one multiple times as an instanced version of the same mesh. If you want variation then make several and use a collection with "pick instance" in your Instance on Points node.

Thanks. Honestly I don't know how to do that, but now I will share my BLEND file with texture.

You can copy UV's from one object (active object) to other objects by selecting all the objects then Shift selecting the object with the correct UV's > Ctrl L > to open the Link/Transfer Data menu and choose the Copy UV Maps option.
As all your leaves are a single mesh object you will first have to separate them into individual objects, do the Copy UV's operation and then join them back to be a single mesh object again.
Before starting be sure you know which leaf has the correct UV unwrap.

Hide the tree object.
In edit mode select all the leaves.
P to open the Separate menu and choose the By Loose Parts option. Now all the leaves are separate objects.
Select all the leaf objects, hold down the Shft key and select the leaf object with the correct UV's.
Ctrl L to open the Link/Transfer data menu and choose the Copy UV's option.
With the all the leaf objects still selected use Ctrl J to join them all to be a single object again.
Now in edit mode, if you select all the leaves and you will see in the UV editor that they are all overlapping.

Edit to add:
I don't understand why, after Link/Transfer Data > Copy UV's even though all the leaves are correctly unwrapped and stacked one above the other in the UV space that some of the leaves have their texture stretched.
After checking your 1.blend file I think I found a solution that works. Instead of the Copy UV's, use the Transfer Mesh Data option.
Ctrl L > Transfer Mesh Data > and in the pop_up menu (bottom left hand corner) set Data Type to UV's,  Face Corner Ma... to Nearest Corner of Nearest Face and check  Auto Transform. see screenshot below:

You will notice that some of the leaves appear to be a lighter green that the others but this is a shader/lighting issue. In the Principled BSDF shader try upping the roughness value so that the leaves are not so shiny.

Thanks. I've followed all these steps. It looks like all leaves have the same UV map, but visually some leaves have stretched textures. I added a screenshot in the first post.

Can you share a little .blend file with an object consisting of a group of say 10 of the leaves before copying the UV's (1 of which is correctly UV unwrapped) and a second objects of the same group after the copy UV operation and add it to your question so we can have a look.  https://blend-exchange.com/ and if possible pack the leaf texture.

Yes, of course. I shared two BLEND files in my question. A leaf texture is packed. I saved all leaves.

I have edited my answer to add what I think is a solution, Instead of Copy UV's use the Transfer Mesh data option.

Thanks. I've done this. Some leaves have wrond orientation (the end of the branch is attached at the opposite leaf side, but that is not so problem, although it is unpleasant). The only problem is that after joining (Ctrl+J) all leaves into one object I get two UV maps, so only one leaf is textured (or only one leaf isn't textured).

I simply solved the problem with two UVs just renaming one, and then joining.
